# Why was migration rejected on this post (SFF to Meta)

Tags: discussion, scope, meta, migration

[Why do people on this site tolerate power users on this forum that debate in bad faith and power trip?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11916/976)

Says Migration Rejected.

This may have been a poor quality post (easily fixable) but it was clearly on-topic on SFF Meta. Why was migration (from main site) rejected?

Comment: It tossed that on there when I cast the last close vote.  I assume the message just comes from the combo of migrated + closed.

Comment: It was off-topic in the sense that the community found it unclear what OP is asking

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to main meta

> A question can also be rejected by the target community after it has already been migrated if it gets closed (except as a duplicate) or deleted on the target site.
>
> <sub>[source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/299342)</sub>

The question was closed on SFF meta (as "unclear what you're asking") so the migration was rejected. I've re-opened and unlocked the question.

Comment: I'm at a loss why you've unilaterally reopened it when there are multiple upvotes to the comment agreeing that it's unclear (more than there were votes).

Comment: @Valorum: Closing that particular question with that particular close reason had really bad optics.  I don't know if that's why Null reopened, but it's not very nice to refuse a clearly frustrated newbie's basic questions about how the site works.

Comment: @Kevin - He's not asking how the site works, he's railing against unspecifed "power users" that he feels have wronged him without offering any examples.

Comment: @Kevin - He also ignored multiple requests asking for more specifics and managed to get into a row with another user who was trying to help them.

Comment: @Valorum - given that people figured out what he was asking about and posted details in comments, that seems like a rather thin excuse (i'm trying to be polite here as to not violate "be nice" rule, my actual opinion on the fact that the question was closed is far less printable)

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To - people shouldn't have to "figure out" what he's referring to from (some cases deleted) comments and by rooting around his activity history to puzzle out who he's managed to get into an argument with. The essence of VTC UNCLEAR is that his question wasn't especially clear.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To - *shrug* it seemed like a good idea at the time.  Not as concerned as some about it being reversed though.